# Make child element 100% width & height of parent element without setting any styles on child element

Tags: html, css

I need to make a `div.child` 100% width and height of `div.parent` without setting any styles on the `div.child` using no script or `::before` or `::after` with pure CSS. Also the `div.child` has no content.

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
 </div>
</div>

.parent {
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this without using any pseudoselectors or applying any elements to the `.child` class is to set the parent to use a grid layout with only one row and one column. This will cause the child to fill the space of the parent, without setting styles on the `.child` itself.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
  display: grid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}


/* Only included to show area of .child element, not necessary */

.child {
  background-color: #aaffaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need to define grid-template-rows or grid-template-columns. Display: grid is enought